# How to make wp-signup.php a 1-step process

Tags: multisite, templates, signup

I'm developing a multisite for Real Estate agents. Wp-signup.php used the wrong page template from my theme (homepage instead of full width page template), so I took the meat and potatoes from wp-signup.php and created a page template out of it.

Here's the result: [http://thewebrockstar.com/realestate/signup/][1]

However now step 2 (after you hit Next) redirects away from my wp-signup page template to the original wp-signup.php.

Is there a solution to this? I was thinking it would be easiest to make wp-signup.php a 1-step process (everything on a single page) instead of this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTP74.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom wp-signup.php, then follow masonjames instruction on the link below:
http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/wp-signupphp#post-39782

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [FAQ#deletion]) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.